# How to automatically manage and update CDK version with Projen?

Tags: aws-cdk, dependabot

**Context:**

[Projen](https://github.com/eladb/projen) is an awesome tool to generate and manage ([JSII](https://github.com/aws/jsii)-built) [AWS CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) projects.

**Background:**

Previously I have managed CDK dependencies with [RenovateBot](https://renovate.whitesourcesoftware.com/)'s [`group:aws-cdkMonorepo`](https://docs.renovatebot.com/presets-group/#groupaws-cdkmonorepo) preset. This will result in RenovateBot creating a single Github Pull Request for AWS CDK depedency updates.

**Question:**

With Projen, one controls the CDK version in `.projenrc.js`:

```js
const { AwsCdkConstructLibrary } = require('projen');

const project = new AwsCdkConstructLibrary({
  authorName: "Example",
  authorAddress: "contact@example.com",
  cdkVersion: "1.64.0",
  name: "@example/project",
  repository: "https://github.com/example/project.git",
});

project.synth();
```

So how can one manage that `cdkVersion` value with tooling such as DependaBot or RenovateBot?

Since keeping one's CDK constructs up-to-date with current CDK version is critial and with multiple CDK constructs doing it by hand will be painful.

Comment: Hey Ari! I have no answer to that, just want to comment on your last paragraph. I read that over and over again, that ppl (think they have to) re-publish their constructs when new CDK versions pop up. I have never done that and I have never had issues with my constructs in newer versions. For instance cdk-iam-floyd depends on cdk `^1.30.0` and I haven't heard any complaints. I myself use this package with CDK 1.64.0.

Answer (score 0):

The central version management depends on your requirement. If you are using a centralized construct library it is a must-have.
For managing the dependencies in centrally in a single configuration, you need to add the following snippet in the `.projenrc.js`

```
cdkDependecies:[
'@aws-cdk/core'
]
```

Now, whenever you run projen the cdk app would be managed centrally and use the latest version.